# Installing CPU With an Attached Heat Sink?

Tags: installation, cpu, motherboard, heatsink

I'm replacing the motherboard on my PC. I removed the heat sink, which is still attached to the CPU because of the thermal paste. I noticed that some pins on the CPU are significantly bent, but I managed to fix them.

Question: How do I re-instal the CPU with the heat sink attached without risking bending more pins?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your CPU?  At the very least, what socket it's using?  Some of these are more problematic than others (and I'm guessing it's old if it's the sort with A: pins and B: where the heatsink can get stuck!  Actually, are you sure it wasn't thermal *epoxy*?  That used to get used a lot.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: How do I re-instal the CPU with the heat sink attached
>   without risking bending more pins?

Use no force when inserting the CPU into its socket. If you are having trouble getting the CPU into the socket, slow down. Try a different orientation. Look at the parts and make sure you are matching them up properly. As soon as you feel that you are applying force, *stop*, you are about to bend some pins! Make sure that the CPU is fully and securely seated before clamping the heatsink down.

Be gentle. Move slowly.

Comment: "If your using force, your probably doing it wrong"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'm going to separate the CPU/Heat sink just in case, and apply them one at a time. I'll have to pick up some thermal paste...

Answer (score 1):

Just as other's have said, if you are using ANY force at all, you are probably bending pins. I would make sure that I am holding the weight of the heat sink too. DO NOT just sit it on the socket, hold the weight. Some heat sinks can be very heavy for those little copper pins to hold that kind of weight.

Just because you straitened the pins doesn't mean it will work again. You may have made some of the pins very thin when bending them, and they may break off into the socket when you put it back into the socket.

GOOD LUCK!!!